# getting error in SSO implementation of saml sso by laravel with using google as idp [app_not_configured_for_user]

Tags: single-sign-on, http-status-code-403, laravel-saml

I've integrated the SAML package in Laravel app and created SAML app at admin.google.com (google console) and configured the urls (entity id , idp , sso , sls, acs). On my project after click on single sign on button it redirects to choose google account(as browser capture multiple login on google login page) and after choosing the particular account shows the error (Tried with incognito mode too.)
[image: This one is the error I am facing each time]

Even user access is ON for everyone in google console setting.
[image: google console having setting for user access enabled]

Can someone help here?

Comment: Most of the time that occurs because the user selected their Gmail account instead of the guitar account that has the same set up